# how to convert an arff file to a matrix

Tags: java, data-mining, arff

I have arff file need to be converted to matrix. I already converted the file to array but  could not convert it to matrix. can someone help. 
below I have the code that i used to convert the data to array

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("colon.arff"));
       ArffReader arff = new ArffReader(reader);
     Instances data = arff.getData();
     data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

     for (int i = 0; i < data.numAttributes(); i++)
{
    // Print the current attribute.
    System.out.print(data.attribute(i) + ": ");

    // Print the values associated with the current attribute.
    double[] values = data.attributeToDoubleArray(i);
   //data= new double [row][col];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}
```

Comment: There is no `Matrix` type in standard Java. So what do you want? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a `double[][]`, proceed as follows:

Collect all the `double[]`s in an `ArrayList<double[]>`.

At the end, use `list.toarray(new double[list.size()][])` or similar to convert the list of dynamic length into an array of *fixed* length.

Or you allocate the output array directly, as `Instances` already knows the number of attributes and instances.

Beware that `double[][]` isn't strictly speaking a matrix. It could be ragged, i.e., rows could have different length. Furthermore, above code would produce a transposed matrix, probably not what you expect. You'll likely want to iterate over instances and use `instance.toDoubleArray()` instead.

By any means, check out the source code of `attributeToDoubleArray` to understand what Weka is doing internally to give you some ideas how to proceed.